# Is it possible to somehow hold onto an Observable's/Flowable's emissions and some way to trigger the emissions as needed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava2, and I have used the other methods `defer`, `concat` and `create`. I am trying to look for a way to implement what I have described above.

The specific need is this, I have a fragment that is shown and hidden. This fragment has `subscribers` to `EventBus` events. The events are triggered by a service that I keep running in the background.

I don't want to lose he emissions when the fragment is hidden. Instead, I would like to somehow `cache` the emissions, emitted while it is hidden and then emit them when the fragment is shown.

Is there a built in solution for this using RxJava2 APIs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The specific need is this, I have a fragment that is shown and hidden.
>   This fragment has subscribers to EventBus events. The events are
>   triggered by a service that I keep running in the background.

I won't use EventBus if I am already using RxJava

> I don't want to lose he emissions when the fragment is hidden.
>   Instead, I would like to somehow cache the emissions, emitted while it
>   is hidden and then emit them when the fragment is shown.

I would use a `ReplaySubject` for this purpose. From the documentation

> ReplaySubject emits to any observer all of the items that were emitted
>   by the source Observable(s), regardless of when the observer
>   subscribes.